# Как правильно подписаться на изменение формы?

Tags: angular

Подскажите, как правильно подписаться на изменение формы? Не могу разобраться. Если подписываюсь в методах, определенных на изменение инпутов и селектов, то получается приложение зависает. Я в ангуларе новичок, не сочтите за труд написать в какую сторону копать. Если с примерами, то будет замечательно. Спасибо.

Это компонента

```
   import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-exchange',
  templateUrl: './exchange.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exchange.component.css']
})

export class ExchangeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  rateUSD: number;

  @Input()
  rateEUR: number;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this._initForm()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  _initForm(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      select1: new FormControl(1, [Validators.required]),
      select2: new FormControl(1, [Validators.required]),
      input1: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      input2: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    })
  }

  functionI1() {
    this.form.setValue({
      input1: this.form.value.input1,
      input2:(this.form.value.input1*this.form.value.select1/this.form.value.select2).toFixed(2),
      select1:this.form.value.select1,
      select2: this.form.value.select2
    })
  }

  functionI2() {
    this.form.setValue({
      input1: (this.form.value.input2*this.form.value.select2/this.form.value.select1).toFixed(2),
      input2: this.form.value.input2,
      select1:this.form.value.select1,
      select2: this.form.value.select2
    })
  }
}
```

Это разметка

```
<div class="wrap-exchange">
  <form [formGroup]="form" >
    <div class="currency-value">
      <div>
        <mat-form-field class="curSelect" color="warn" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Продаж</mat-label>
          <mat-select (selectionChange)="functionI1()" formControlName="select1">
            <mat-option [value]="rateUSD">USD</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="rateEUR">EUR</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]=1>UAH</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="curSelect" color="warn" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Купівля</mat-label>
          <mat-select (selectionChange)="functionI2()" formControlName="select2">
            <mat-option [value]="rateUSD">USD</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="rateEUR">EUR</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]=1>UAH</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" color="warn">
          <mat-label>Сума</mat-label>
          <input (change)="functionI1()" type="number" matInput placeholder="Value" formControlName="input1">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" color="warn">
          <mat-label>Сума</mat-label>
          <input (change)="functionI2()" type="number" matInput placeholder="Value" formControlName="input2">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: пытаюсь понять тоже самое. мб нашел ответ?